# python BST error of "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, binary-search-tree

```
class BST:
    class TreeNode:
        def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
            self.data = data
            self.left = left
            self.right = right
    
    # Self constructor for initialization
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root
```

```
    def countNodes(self):
        nodeCount = 0
        curNode = self.root
        if curNode is not None:
            if curNode.left is not None:
                nodeCount += 1
                self.countNodes(curNode.left)
            if curNode.right is not None:
                nodeCount += 1
                self.countNodes(curNode.right)     
        return nodeCount
```

Im pretty stumped on this I am just not seeing a solution to my problem at hand.
I am trying to just count the amount of nodes in a binary search tree, I think I am not able to implement recursive functions into my program how should I approach this problem.
I understand recursion in theory I am just confused about the purpose of self

Error Message:

```
                45
            35
        30
            25
                16
    15
        14
10
            9
        8
            4
    2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-9edfda5068f6> in <module>
    210     #finding maximum value of the tree
    211     print(tree.findMax())
--> 212     print(tree.countNodes())
    213     tree.delete(69)
    214     tree.print()

<ipython-input-5-9edfda5068f6> in countNodes(self)
    138             if curNode.left is not None:
    139                 nodeCount += 1
--> 140                 countNodes(curNode.left)
    141             if curNode.right is not None:
    142                 nodeCount += 1

NameError: name 'countNodes' is not defined
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **full text** of the error or traceback you're getting.

Comment: In `self.countNodes(curNode.left)` (and `self.countNodes(curNode.right)`) you pass an unexpected extra parameter. Should be `curNode.left.countNodes()`.

Comment: When I do curNode.left.countNodes() I get the attribute error of 'TreeNode' object has no attrivute 'countNodes'

Comment: Then your tree design (which you did not show) is wrong.